# Webvitals Main-Thread Blocking Time

Tags: javascript, web, facebook-comments, web-vitals

```js
function init() {  
      (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=1111";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
        
}
window.onload = init;
```

Despite the fact that I am calling [facebook comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) on load still i am getting a minus score on web-vitals
as its part of [Main-Thread Blocking Time](https://web.dev/tbt/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to load the `facebook_comments` plugin.

> Web Workers are a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads.

Here's an example:

`facebook_comments.js`:

```
function init() {  
      (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=1111";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))    
}
```

and then load it via the web worker:

```
new Worker('facebook_comments.js');
```

That should load the script in a background thread, resulting to an optimized TBT.